# REST function can not be invoked

Tags: c#, json, rest, visual-studio-2013

I have a WCF service which functions I am using in my web api MVC app. The error I came across is:

```
"No action was found on the controller that matches the request"
```

The problem would not be so strange if my earlier functions don't work, but they do. 
Here is my code...

```
[ActionName("restfunctionname")]
public SortedList<string, PropertyClass> REST_Function([ModelBinder(typeof (CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))] string[] parameterList, string parameter2, string parameter3)
        {
            WCF wcfService = new WCF();

            List<string> arrayParameter = new List<string>();
            ids.AddRange(parameterList);

            SortedList<string, PropertyClass> returnValue = wcfService.GetTranslationsFromId(arrayParameter, paremeter2, parameter3);

            return returnValue;
        }
```

So, return value should be SortedList.

Since I am in MVC, in my WebApiConfig I set this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "restfunctionname",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{parameterList}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}",
                defaults: new { parameterList= RouteParameter.Optional, parameter2 = RouteParameter.Optional, parameter3 = RouteParameter.Optional }

            );
```

Finally, I call my function from browser trying to catch JSON in response body like this:

```
http://localhost:20915/api/controller/restfunction/firstItemOfArray,SecondItemOfArray/parameter2/parameter3
```

... but nothing. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your controller name ?  Also your function is named Rest_functuion not restfunction

Comment: @nsgocev OK, I am new to the REST and as you can see all the names are modified. I wanted to be descriptive. I am putting the good name for the controller, because as I said the earlier functions are working. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: http://localhost:20915/api/controller : instead of controller you should pass the name of your controller (i.e. name of the controller class). say if the name of your controller is XController, your url should look like http://localhost:20915/api/X/[rest of the URL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have word "GET" in my WCF functions, for example... My original WCF function name was: TranslationFromID and then I changed it to: GetTranslationFromID and now it works.